# Fixed length string from an integer - reduce allocation?

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to write a fixed length file of multiple Gigabytes in size, and would like to reduce the string allocation of the process.

Currently I am doing this:

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        foreach (var cellInfo in cellInfos)
            streamWriter.Write($"{cellInfos.Info1[i],-10}{cellInfos.Info2[i],-10}");

        streamWriter.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Since it is a fixed length file I have condidered instead of calling `Write(string)` to call `Write(byte[])` and somehow turn the int values to an byte array with padding.

`cellInfos.Info1[i]` and `cellInfos.Info2[i]` are both of type `int`, so the fixed length file will look something like this at the end:

```
114001    2979993   1         2238001   324585    2985606   2980884   2532097   2532097   2980884   1         2985606   1         2985606   1492803   1         2791025   2485160   1492803   1         2106095   2720047   971452    2952105   1         2985606   1         2985606   324585    2985606   1195045   2985606   
365001    2973993   1402746   1442502   223569    2738205   1121779   2744137   2744137   1121779   1990399   995210    1990399   995210    1759696   1944745   1598017   2485161   1703338   1195696   979974    2720052   251107    2975092   1990399   995210    1990399   995210    223569    2738205   1130022   995240
```

Pseudo code I have in mind

```
//each cellInfos will output 2 values and each value will have a maxLength of 10
var byteArray = new byte[cellInfos.Count * 2 * 10];
var newLineBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName)))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        foreach (var cellInfo in cellInfos)
        {
             //set values into the array 
             byteArray[0] = cellInfos.Info1[i].GetFirstByte();
             byteArray[1] = cellInfos.Info1[i].GetSecondByte();
             ...
        }    

        fs.Write(byteArray);
        fs.Write(newLineBytes);
    }
}
```

I have currently no idea how I could turn my pseudo code into reality.

Comment: You might want to consider using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-7.0#definition) to build each line.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - I would have imagined writing the StringBuilder first and than the StringBuilder to the file would perform worse than writing the file directly, so you are saying that's not the case?

Comment: Interpolated strings are highly optimised to avoid allocations in newer .NET versions, and `StringBuilder` is also optimised to avoid allocations when used with an interpolated string. I think you'll have to benchmark those two options however -- I'm not sure whether one big string or lots of little strings will come out worse

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines, since you ware writing multiple Gigabytes

Comment: Either way you're writing to a file, so the filesystem I/O will be a much bigger limit than minor differences like this

Comment: But why? The advantage of text-based formats is that they are human readable. "Multiple gigabytes" does not sound human readable to me, and would be a strong hint to use some type of binary format.

Comment: @JonasH - it isn't supposed to be human readable, the file is produced with sorting indexes for a database and has to be this format for my database server (firebird) to insert into as an external file (yes, writing the data directly to the database is significant slower) - if you want to read up the topic: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-external

Comment: @Jodrell - thanks for the link, will have a look at it

Comment: @canton7 - okay, will try to benchmark big string vs lots of little strings

Comment: _"will try to benchmark"_ - I guess you know [BenchmarkDotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org) ?

Comment: But, since this use-case involves writing GBs of data to file, I'd be tempted to set up a test which does that. Details in the string creation don't really matter unless they have an effect on the speed of the overall file write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Span<char>` and `TryFormat` method.

```
Span<char> span = stackalloc char[10];

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    ...
        cellInfo.Info1.TryFormat(span, out charsWritten);
        span[charsWritten..].Fill(' ');
        streamWriter.Write(span);

        cellInfo.Info2.TryFormat(span, out charsWritten);
        span[charsWritten..].Fill(' ');
        streamWriter.Write(span);
        
        streamWriter.WriteLine();
    ...
}
```

This will eliminate memory allocations for strings.

Comment: Thanks alot gives roughly double the performance, had to do a slight change since it used `(char)0` on the "non-occupied" indexes, so I added a simple loop - `for (var index = written; index < 10; index++) span[index] = ' ';` and changed `out int _` to `out int written` to get info how many indexes got written into. If you happen to know a better way, please share your idea.

Comment: @RandRandom - `span.Slice(start, lenth).Fill(' ')`.  That said, you should really use Pipelines (above example) as it's specifically designed to solve the problem.  If you want to use Span<T> - use `writer.GetSpan(10)`.  I would avoid `stackalloc` for what you're doing as you can get yourself into trouble with loops and async.  And it's not shouldn't make that much of a difference in performance difference vs the alternative.

Comment: @AdamCohen - thanks for the input, I will definatily give your answer a chance aswell, though it will take till tomorrow, busy with other stuff at the moment

Comment: @RandRandom - no rush.  when you kick the tires - do a run with the buffer increased from `4096` to `2 << 20` or `1 << 20` to see if it makes a difference

Comment: @RandRandom - also - in case you end up going w/ `stackalloc`, you need to clear the buffer after every write.

Answer (score 1):

PipeWriter backed by MemoryPool should reduce allocations and GC pressure.  See example below...

NOTE - THIS HAS NEVER BEEN RUN.  MAKE SURE TO DILLIGENCE THE CODE...

```
// set path and replace stringData with your row in the code below.
var path = "file to write";
Span<byte> newLine = new byte[] { (byte)'\n', 0x00 };
Span<char> charBuffer = new char[10]; Span<byte> byteBuffer = new byte[10];

using var writeStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create,
  FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, FileOptions.SequentialScan);

// adjust buffer from 4096 -> 512 or increase to  2 << 20 for higher throughput
PipeWriter writer = PipeWriter.Create(writeStream,
    new StreamPipeWriterOptions(MemoryPool<byte>.Shared, 4096, false));

//loop and write your data...
for (int row = 0; row < rowsCount; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < colCount; col++) 
    {
        cellInfos[row][col].Info1.TryFormat(charBuffer, out var written);
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charBuffer, byteBuffer);
        writer.Write(byteBuffer);
        charBuffer.Clear(); byteBuffer.Clear();

        cellInfos[row][col].Info2.TryFormat(charBuffer, out written);
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charBuffer, byteBuffer);
        writer.Write(byteBuffer);
        charBuffer.Clear(); byteBuffer.Clear();
    }
    writer.Write(newLine);
}
```

If this isn't sufficient, I would suggest StringPool from MS HighPerformance Toolkit, but it's probably overkill.